# Linking External CSS

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

What is the format for linking a Microsite page (CloudPages) to a stylesheet/code resource?

I've tried directly using the generated link as well as the CloudPagesURL function to no avail. I've found no documentation outlining this process directly either (other answers I found are based on previous UI structure).

Note: I did publish & refresh the page and checked the changes there, not in the preview pane.

I'm sure to be overlooking something simple.
Many thanks,

Comment: Also tried using filename & again with path since these are in the same collection with the same result.